# Is there a way to hide credentials in Stomp?

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, rabbitmq, stomp

I am running on ***Nette framework***. I am trying to listen to ***RabbitMQ messages*** and update the browser with JavaScript when a message is received. One idea was to use stomp.js to listen to the message queue directly from the browser, but it seems I cannot hide credentials. Is there any way so that ***the client can't see 'guest', 'guest' and 'ws://localhost:15674/ws'?*** (Note that we don't use node.js)

```
let client = Stomp.client("ws://localhost:15674/ws");

client.heartbeat.outgoing = 0;
client.heartbeat.incoming = 0;

client.debug = onDebug;

client.connect("guest", "guest", onConnect, onError, "/");`
```

Would it maybe be possible to listen to messages with PHP on the backend side and update the page asynchronously? I am lost at this, it needs to be secure...

Comment: This is why standards like OAuth were created.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to hide anything in JS code from the client, after all if the browser can't read the code, how can it execute it?

I think you'll need to implement some backend code to act as a middleman between the frontend and the queue

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem seems to be that I am unable to run a RabbitMQ consumer in PHP, because, as far as I know, it can only be started using CLI, but our framework with authorization makes it impossible for me to run internal scripts using CLI. Maybe if there was a way to start the consumer from the code?